# GroovyFX: using calendarTextField from jfxtras

Tags: groovy, javafx, jfxtras, groovyfx

I would like to use the calendarTextField fomr jfxtras in the same way I use textFields.
I.e. I would like to be able to set row, column, columnSpan in a gridPane.

I registered the calenderTextField with

```
    registerBeanFactory "calendarTextField", CalendarTextField
```

but I cannot use the row property

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: row for class: jfxtras.labs.scene.control.CalendarTextField
```

this is somewhat clear, since the calendarField does not have a row property, but I looked into javafx.Textfield: this doesn't have a row property, too.

How is this working? What do I have to do in order to be able to use the row property for the calendarTextField.

row comes from `GridConstraints`... but how are they related with the text field (or `TextInputControl`) in GroovyFX ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Found out, that eclipse was cheating me... the run-configuration does not refresh, if the project classpath is refreshed... integrating CalendarTextField works perfectly with GroovyFX